# Efficiently Scroll and Zoom Photos Using UIScrollView and UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, scroll, zooming

I need a simple way of scrolling through photos and zooming each photo as needed. Just like original Apple's Photo app. I understand the concept: UIScrollView has many UIScrollView  subviews as pages and each of those has a UIImageView to zoom in.

However, I've also seen an example, which I can no longer find, with more efficient way of doing this - using only 3 pages (UIScrollView's) for as many photos as there are to save memory usage. So basically, if there are 10 photos, only 3 pages shown (centered visible, left hidden, right hidden) and as you scroll left or right new images are being placed into those pages to simulate an effect of continuous scroll.

My question is how is this done or is there an existing example so I do not reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna take a look at MWPhotoBrowser, it's pretty the same as the Photo app.

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Comment: Yes, I found this one a few days ago. I think it's a good project to look at. Thanks